# Center larger element inside smaller container element

Tags: html, css

How do you make an image centered without covering up the paragraph below it? `position: absolute;` or `float: left;` will both cause problems.

```
<p>This is the first paragraph</p>
<p><img src="http://placekitten.com/600/280"/></p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

Assuming the following CSS:

```
p { width: 100px; margin: 0 auto}
```

I would also like to make sure the larger img element is not `overflow:hidden` by the parent `p` tag. I want to see the full image even if it's too big.

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/9twojm9g/).

Comment: why u dont use `position: absolute;` and fix the image with `top` and `left` and other orientations.but this way is not recommended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to keep the fixed width paragraph, you could use the following to center the image:

```
img {
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
       -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
         -o-transform:translateX(-50%);
            transform:translateX(-50%);
    margin-left:50%;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is pretty neat. Only works in modern browsers, but that is all I have to worry about. ([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/9twojm9g/7/))

Answer (score 0):

USE Jquery...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/remix1201/9twojm9g/6/

HTML:

```
<p>This is the first paragraph</p>
<p class="center"><img src="http://placekitten.com/600/280"/></p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
```

CSS:

```
p { max-width: 100px; max-height: 300px; background: #eee; padding: 1em; margin: 0 auto}
```

JS: (jquery)

```
var getContWidth = $("p").width();
var getImgWidth = $("p.center img").width();
var adjustMargin = (getImgWidth - getContWidth)/2;
$("p.center img").css("margin-left","-" + adjustMargin + "px");
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/frankDraws/ojcf7gz5/2/)?

I took a different approach and hope it helps. Let me know if this works for you.

```
<div class="container">
    <p>This is the first paragraph</p>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/280"/>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>

body {
    background-color: white;
}
.container {
    width:auto;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: #eee;
}
p { 
    padding: 1em; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; }

img {
    /* position: absolute; left: 0; */
    /* position: absolute; float: left; */
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is totally different. The reason this works is because you removed the 100px limit and made the `img` container (the `p` tag) just as big as the image.

Comment: See the comment on @trysmudford's answer